# How to write Transactional Unit Tests for Transactional Methods in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

The Unit-Test Classes I have in my Project extend an `AbstractUnitTest` class which is `@Transactional`. The tests in these classes are running on some methods which themselves are `@Transactional`.

Whenever these methods bring tested fail, instead of rolling back, the Transactions are partially persisted (*in the Testing Environment, ordinarily they behave atomically*). 
This is preventing me from testing Transactional behavior of my  Project Modules.

*More specifically*, I have a Unit-Test for an `addList()` method. However, on encountering an Exception, during unit-testing, the input list is partially added and not rolled back *since*, the test is itself running in a Transaction(by virtue of `AbstractUnitTest` being Transactional)

On removing the `@Transactional` from `AbstractUnitTest`, the tests work fine.
What is the reason for this behavior and **how can you perform unit-testing of Transactional methods if the Unit Test class itself is Transactional?**

Answer (score 1):

that depends on your configuration I think: if you want to start a transaction you need to configure a TransactionManager for your unit testing. 
As you use Spring make sure this is configured and the transaction boundaries (begin/commit or rollback) are defined to ensure the transactional behavior (rollback upon error).

My advice is anyway to use TransactionalTestExecutionListener to always rollback after each test: in this way each test is independent as it always runs with the same data.

Hope this helps.

Beppe